# My method doesn't resize the width and the height of images it just resize the size

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

My method doesn't resize the width and the height of the image it just resize the size of it.

I used a python library which is PIL.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
def resizeImg(img):
  mywidth = 320
  wpercent = (mywidth/float(img.size[0]))
  hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
  img = img.resize((mywidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
  return img
```

The image was in 1MB now it's just 130KB, is that normal? I was expecting to get different width and height.

Comment: Why did you remove the `import` statements, which must be in your code, so that no-one else can run it? Please provide your starting image so we can see what you are working with? What result were you expecting when you changed the width and height - you seem surprised that the file has come out smaller?

Comment: I believe what you are saying is that you tried to crop the image by a `bbox`(particular dimension), but rather its size got changed(by size i mean the number of pixels used to represent the image (x,y)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this looks normal.
What you're doing is that you are actually resampling the image.

If your input image as a horizontal pixel size superior to 320 pixels, you are effectively reducing the definition (number of pixels) hence the inferior file size.
If you don't want to change the definition but only want to change the printing/display size for example you might consider scaling the dpi.

This can be be done when saving by doing something like this :

```
img.save(filepath, format=fmt, dpi=(dpi, dpi))
```

You have to calculate the horizontal and vertical dpi value as desired.
This won't change the file size.